# sharepoint 2013 create document library using List Template C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list, sharepointdocumentlibrary, sharepoint-listtemplate

It is possible to used a **list template** to create new document library, I am trying following code but its is not working.it just create library without using template.

```
ListTemplateCollection listTemplates1 = context.Site.GetCustomListTemplates(context.Web);
ListTemplate li1;//
context.Load(listTemplates1);
context.ExecuteQuery();
context.Load(site.ListTemplates);
context.ExecuteQuery();

var listTemplate = listTemplates1.First(lt => lt.Name == "<Test>");

ListCreationInformation li = new ListCreationInformation();
li.Title = "XYZZ2";
li.Description = "Created through Code";
li.TemplateFeatureId = listTemplate.FeatureId;
li.TemplateType = listTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind;
List newList = context.Web.Lists.Add(li);
context.Load(newList);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you directly try to fetch the template instead of getting the entire collection like the following:

```
ListTemplate listTemplate = context.web.ListTemplates.GetByName("templateName"); 
context.Load(listTemplate);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Then create your list,

```
ListCreationInformation li = new ListCreationInformation();
li.Title = "XYZZ2";
li.Description = "Created through Code";
li.TemplateFeatureId = listTemplate.FeatureId;
li.TemplateType = listTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind;
List newList = context.Web.Lists.Add(li);
context.Load(newList);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

This may be because the listTemplate, in your case, has not been initialized properly which is why the List was getting created with the default template.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried your code for fetching templates but i got default templates, i have created custom templates(which contains document library with folder structure) i want to use that. How to fetch custom templates.

Comment: @AbhijeetSutar did you find answer for your question about custom template?